# C strtok token manipulation

Tags: c, strtok

So i have a program that reads a txt file. Then I use strtok to tokenize the strings using ";" as a separator. The problem is that I have to horizontally format those tokens similar to an sql query. The only thing I get is to make the tokens be printed vertically. I am so confused.

This is my code.
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
    #include 
    #include

```
int i, j;
FILE *fdin;
char *p;
char s_line[120];


char *token;
const char s[2] = ";";
int main()
{
    if ((fdin = fopen("raw14.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(s_line, sizeof(s_line), fdin))
    {   
        /*get first token */
        token = strtok(s_line, s);

        p = &s_line[strlen(s_line) - 1];
        if (*p < ' ')
            *p = '\0';
        /*Loop for Serarating*/
        while (token){

            printf("Description")
            printf(" %s\n", token);


            token = strtok(NULL, s);
       }

   }

   printf("\n\n");

   return 0;
}
```

The result should look like this:

ITEM ID DESCRIPTION             QTY IN   QTY OUT    BALANCE

240201  AEROSIL              |   253.50    231.00 |    22.50

240202  ALCOHOL              |   663.00    412.78 |   250.22

the txt part is like that:

240201;AEROSIL;253.5;231
240202;ALCOHOL;663;412.78

Please note that I have no idea how to create an extra balance column and also put the pipelines only with an strtok. I do get that I should also use left side justification and format the printf in order to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to horizontally format those tokens

So why then you print a newline (`'\n'`) after each token?

Instead of

```
    while (token) {

        printf("Description")
        printf(" %s\n", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
```

you might do

```
    while (token) {

        printf("Description")
        printf(" %s", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks seems like that was my minor problem. I edited the question.

Comment: @PetrosKoklas: So please what is your *major* problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You have a \n (newline character) in your printf, so each token is printed on its own line.

Change this

```
while (token){
    printf("Description")
    printf(" %s\n", token);


    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
```

to this

```
while (token) {
    printf(" %s", token);
    token = strtok(NULL, s);
}
printf("\n"); // Put the newline character outside the loop.
```

You should also print the Description ID BALANCE text outside the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks seems like that was my minor problem. I edited the question.

Comment: The items are separated by space or by a newline?

Comment: If they are separated by space, then use the space character ' ' as a delimeter on strtok() and then use sscanf() to parse the arguments like this: sscanf(token, "%d;%s;%lf;%lf", &itemID, description, &qty, &d); (int itemID, char description[40], double qty, double balance).

Comment: If they are separated by a newline character, then just use fgets() and sscanf(), no need to use strtok().

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a new line each time you're printing the token.
If you want them to print like `CHOCOLATE 1 4`, just use `printf("%s ", token);` in your loop. And you shouldn't print Description inside your loop too.

Comment: Thanks seems like that was my minor problem. I edited the question.